# Problems with percentages in IE css

Tags: css, html, percentage

I'm creating some div elements. Then I'm trying to give the divs width and height using percentages. Nothing happens. 
What is the problem?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/48/)

HTML:

```
<!--Wrapper div-->
    <div id="wrapper">
       <div id="inbox">

        </div> 

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    background-color:yellowgreen;
}

#wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #ffffcc;
    min-width: 700px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #828282;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #828282;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #828282;
}

#inbox {
    width:60%;
    height:70%;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `height:100%` to `html, body` and `#wrapper` in css

Here's an updated fiddle : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62QY8/49/)

Answer (score 2):

It is working except your div has no height.  Either set a min-height or add some content.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify some form of `height` for each parent element of `#inbox`, including `html`.

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
    min-height:70%;  
}

#inbox {
    height:70%; 
}
```